# Vertically centralising content in an inline-block

Tags: html, css

I’m trying to get the blue text vertically in the centre of the inline-block `div`s. I’ve tried various variations but to no avail. The parent must stay as an inline block.

If the parent is displayed as a `table` and child as a table cell with `vertical-align: middle` then it almost works, but fails because then the child div is 100% high, and I want to add a `border-top` and bottom with about `10px` padding, which won’t work at 100% height. Cannot use `display: flex` because it destroys the positioning of other elements. Line height also fails.

Can someone explain what the problem is here because I'm very confused.

```css
.matches-container {
  padding-top: 50px;
}

.match {
  width: 25%;
  height: 250px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid yellow;
}

.match-contents {
  background: blue;
  border-top: 1px solid red;
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}

.a {
  background: black
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<section class="matches-container">
  <article class="match a">
    <div class="match-contents">central text with borders top and bottom</div>
  </article>
  <!-- -->
  <article class="match b">
    <div class="match-contents">central text with borders top and bottom</div>
  </article>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `display: inline-flex` and `align-items: center` here. Demo:

```css
.matches-container {
  padding-top: 50px;
}

.match {
  width: 25%;
  height: 250px;
  /* become inline flex-container */
  display: inline-flex;
  /* center items */
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid yellow;
}

.match-contents {
  background: blue;
  border-top: 1px solid red;
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}

.a {
  background: black
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<section class="matches-container">
  <article class="match a">
    <div class="match-contents">central text with borders top and bottom</div>
  </article>
  <!-- -->
  <article class="match b">
    <div class="match-contents">central text with borders top and bottom</div>
  </article>
</section>
```

Answer (score 3):

Add this properties in `.match-contents`

```
.match-contents {
    position:relative;
    top:50%;
    transform:translateY(-50%);
}
```

Your code is working as expected...no where you added a property to make blue box vertically center.

Here is snippet.

```css
.matches-container {
    padding-top: 50px;
}

.match {
    width: 25%;
    height: 250px;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid yellow;
}

.match-contents {
    background: blue;
    border-top: 1px solid red;
    border-bottom: 1px solid red;
 
 
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.a {
    background: black
}
```

```html
<section class="matches-container">
    <article class="match a">
        <div class="match-contents">central text with borders top and bottom</div>
    </article>
    <!--
            
            -->
    <article class="match b">
        <div class="match-contents">central text with borders top and bottom</div>
    </article>
</section>
```